# How to write a method that works like form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

For my application it would be helpful for me to structure the HTML generation that is quite gnarly into a set of calls that look like `form_for`. Here's an example, from `_reports.html.erb`:

```
<%= reports_list do |rep| %>
  <%= rep.group_header("Reports by Question") do %>
    <%= rep.title("Response Distribution") %>
    <%= rep.description do %>
      lorem lorem lorem
      lorem lorem lorem
    <%= end %>
    <%= rep.title("Response Distribution") %>
    <%= rep.description do %>
      lorem lorem lorem
      lorem lorem lorem
    <%= end %>
  <%= end %>
<%= end %>
```

Each of these calls generates a bit of HTML with CSS and tags and so on which would totally obscure the structure of this list of report list.

I tried reading `form_for` but I'm having trouble untangling it into the pattern that I need. What sort of things can I try?

Comment: Use blocks and `content_tag`.

Comment: Any more detail? I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small custom DSL (you can improve and make the code better):

Small DSL that can be much improved:

```
class ReportHtmlMaker
  def initialize(output)
    @output = output
  end

  def content(text)
    @output << text.to_s
    nil
  end

  def translate_semantic_tag(tagname,attributes={})
    newline = "" # "\r\n" uncomment to add newlines
    case tagname.to_sym
    when :group_header
      tagname = "h1"
      attributes[:id] =  "report_group_header"
    when :title
      tagname = "h2"
      attributes[:class] =  "report_title"
    when :description
      tagname = "p"
    end

    @output << "<#{tagname}"
    attributes.each { |attr,value| @output << " #{attr}='#{value}'" }
    if block_given?
      @output << ">" << newline
      content = yield
      if content
        @output << content.to_s << newline
      end
      @output << "</#{tagname}>" << newline
    else
      @output << "/>" << newline
    end
    nil
  end
  alias method_missing translate_semantic_tag

  def self.generate(output, &block)
    ReportHtmlMaker.new(output).instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
output = String.new
ReportHtmlMaker.generate(output) do  #or, use STDOUT to output to console
  group_header do
    title do
      "Response Distribution"
    end
    description do
      "lorem ipsum dolor mit"
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
puts output # =>

<div id='report_group_header'>
  <h2 class='report_title'>Response Distribution</h2>
  <p class='report_description'>lorem ipsum dolor mit</p>
</h1>
```

Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. It's close... I want to be able to use it in Rails 3 with the 'new' use of <%= vs <% so it looks a lot like the way things look with form_for -- see my sample above. I was going down using 'capture' as it seems to be the way to go these days. Do you know about that stuff?